# Silverlight DataForm - Nested Dataform - How to BeginEdit?

Tags: silverlight, dataform

I have a Silverlight User Control.  This contains a DataForm.  This DataForm nests another Silverlight User Control, which also contains a DataForm.

I have bound the nested dataform successfully to an object in the parent control.

I can NOT however, get the nested control to enter Edit mode along with the parent.   I have tried calling it directly by using the *FindNameInContent* method to return the nested dataform and then called BeginEdit() but this fails (returns false).

Stuck.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?  Trtying to do the same thing, with nested DataForms but cannot get the templates right.  Can you post your samples?

Answer (score 0):

I had a simpler scenario but a similar problem. In my scenario I had a DataGrid directly nested inside a DataForm, and was unable to synchronize the edit modes of the two controls until I realised that I needed to implement an EditTemplate for the DataForm, as well as the ReadOnlyTemplate, and implement the DataGrid in both. I set IsReadOnly=true for the DataGrid in the ReadOnlyTemplate and IsReadOnly=false for the DataGrid in the EditTemplate, and it all works smoothly, with no code.

Dave.